# Finite-state machine for counting of "int" operators in file- didn't work

Tags: c

I have a project to make a Finite-state machine. The program must open the file and analyze it for the 'Int' and 'float' statements and save the results to a new file. Here is the code for Finite-state machine:

```
typedef enum sta_word{None, In_int, End_int} s_INT;
s_INT ComputeInt(int c, char* INT, s_INT status);



s_INT ComputeInt(int c, char* INT, s_INT status)
{
    static int ind = 0;
    char ch = c;
    if (status == End_int)
    {
        status = None;
        ind = 0;
    }
    switch (status)
    {
    case None:
        if (ch!='int')
        {
            status = In_int;
            INT[ind++] = c;
        }break;

    case In_int:
        if (ch=='int')
        {
            status = End_int;
            INT[ind] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            INT[ind++] = c;
        }
        break;
    }
    return status;
}
```

That is counting function: (FILE* fp is opened file for reading)

```
int CountINT(FILE* fp)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("count.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: ");
    }
    int br_INT = 0;
    int c;
    s_INT status = None;
    char INT[256];
    rewind(fp);
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        status = ComputeInt(c, INT, status);
        if (status == End_int)
        {
            br_INT++;
        }
    } while (c != EOF);
    fprintf(file, "\n\ncompute %d INT Operators into file", br_INT);
    return 0;
}
```

but when i open the file for writing there is nothing.

Comment: If you put the state machine aside, do you manage to simply write "Hello." to the file? Ot to put it differently, are you sure that your [mre] is minimal? (No mentioning that the shown code falls short of being an MRE in other respects...)

Comment: `ch=='int'` Will this ever work? You're comparing a character to another character composed of 3 characters?

Comment: Also have you tried calling `fflush` on the file after writing to it?

Comment: `char ch; ...ch!='int'` is never true.  That compares a character to a value outside the character range.